# Send Webrequest via JavaScript to Openproject

Tags: javascript, api, webrequest, openproject

I hope you can try to help me with my current problem.
My task is to send a webrequest (POST) to an API. The API in question is from Openproject

This is our idea:

- User sends an idea through a Sharepoint-Webpage to Openproject, a
  work-package will be created automatically (that works)
- The OpenProject-Response gets logged, the ID of the work-package gets
  extracted (that works)
- Now that we have the ID, an attachment can be sent to that one, if there was one provided by the   user.  (this doesnt work)

Since the API demands a form-data/multipart, we tried a form like this (Javascript):

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='metadata' Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8", "{ 'fileName': 'cute-cat.png', 'description': { 'raw': 'A cute kitty, cuddling with its friends!'} })");

form.append("'file'; 'filename'='attachment'Content-Type: image/png", <filedata>);
```

Thats the best idea we could come up with (i have no experience with anything like that)

When we send the request through the browser (Firefox or Chrome), we get the error

"400 - Bad Request".
urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:InvalidRequestBody"

The content of the request we sent through the browser looks like this:

```
   -----------------------------264232436135129208361200980561

   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Disposition: form-data; name='metadata' Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"



{ 'fileName': 'cute-cat.png', 'description': { 'raw': 'A cute kitty, cuddling with its friends!'} }

   -----------------------------264232436135129208361200980561

   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; 'filename'='attachment'Content-Type: image/png"

  <data>
  
  -----------------------------264232436135129208361200980561--
```

Mind you that the Browser automatically appends the "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="-part, even though we provide it. If we dont include that part in our form-data-variable that we send, we still get the same error, the browser will interpret the multiple values of the variable just as a long string.

If I use exactly the Code i mentioned above, it works perfectly via Postman. But as soon as i put those lines into the Sharepoint-Page and execute the script, it shows the error.

Do you guys have any idea, how to properly create this form-data/multipart-Object (or what the name for that is?
The official documentation of Openproject looks like this:

```
To add an attachment to a work package, a client needs to issue a request of type multipart/form-data with exactly two parts.

The first part must be called metadata. Its content type is expected to be application/json, the body must be a single JSON object, containing at least the fileName and optionally the attachments description.

The second part must be called file, its content type should match the mime type of the file. The body must be the raw content of the file. Note that a filename must be indicated in the Content-Disposition of this part, however it will be ignored. Instead the fileName inside the JSON of the metadata part will be used.

    Content-Type: multipart/form-data

    Body

    --boundary-delimiter
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

    {
      "fileName": "cute-cat.png",
      "description": {
        "raw": "A cute kitty, cuddling with its friends!"
      }
    }

    --boundary-delimiter
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="attachment"
    Content-Type: image/png

    PNG file data
    --boundary-delimiter--
```

Sorry if those questions are pretty dumb, but i dont know it any better.
Any help is appreciated.